# How to display optionsCaption default on a select after click in Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a simple form that you can submit multiple times (via AJAX) that has a dropdown, a text input, and a submission button - the select dropdown in particular has its options bound via `Knockout`. When a user clicks `submit` currently, the data they entered in the text input remains and so does their selected option. Here's the form:

```
<select data-bind="options: users, optionsText: 'UserName', optionsValue: 'UserId', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: addedUserId"></select>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: addedUserIdText" />

<input class="addButton" type="submit" name="addSubmitter" value="ADD" data-bind="enable: addedUserId, click: userFormClick" />
```

What I need to happen is that **I want to clear the text input and reset the select dropdown to "Select..."** when the submit button is clicked. Clearing the text field is very simple:

```
self.addedUserIdText("");
```

But how exactly do I go about resetting the submit dropdown to just have the `optionsCaption` default of "Select..."? I can't exactly reset the value, since that is tied to the literal option value. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set the value to undefined:

```
self.addedUserId(undefined);
```

Comment: So simple, who knew! Thank you Wayne.